# No such provider: SunJCE--Paytm Checksum genrator Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm for our android app.

New PaytmOrder object requires checksumhash as parameter.

To generate checksumhash, we are using jar file recommended from paytm.

https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Google_App_Engine_Kit

We have added this jar in our lib folder.

```
implementation files('src/main/libs/pg-checksum-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
```

This is the code used to generate checksumhash in our android app.

```
try{
    String checkSum =  CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper().genrateCheckSum("7MTqfy715ot231CT",  convertToTreeMap(paramMap));
    paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH" , checkSum);
    System.out.println("Paytm Payload: "+ paramMap);
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But we are getting below exception below when trying to get checksumhash.

```
System.err: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No such provider: SunJCE

2020-01-01 11:32:33.581 26112-26112 W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:671)

2020-01-01 11:32:33.581 26112-26112 W/System.err:     at com.paytm.pg.crypto.AesEncryption.encrypt(AesEncryption.java:34)

2020-01-01 11:32:33.581 26112-26112/System.err:     at com.paytm.pg.merchant.CheckSumServiceHelper.genrateCheckSum(CheckSumServiceHelper.java:53)
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @ManishKumawat see my answer.Try getting hash-map value from application server of yours. Don't try to generate checksum hash locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem when i started generating checksum hash from my application server.
The above issue occurred because i was trying to generate checksum hash in android locally.

Comment: So there is no way to generate checksum in android? Actually Paytm documentation code says that it can be generated in android

Comment: @ManishKumawat yup i too believed that documentation and was catching tails in air.So please dont do that .get that details from server side and finish the work easily bro

Answer (score 3):

I Solve my Issue To generate Check Sum in Android Side.

download this jar (paytm-checksum-1.1.jar) and de-compile it properly, include all java class in your project replace this line in AesEncryption class.And use Base64Encoder jar
this (sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar).

```
//Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING", "SunJCE");// replace this
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // by this line
```

to Know more,follow this url https://medium.com/@dharmmobiledev/paytm-checksum-generate-in-android-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-sunjce-e02c216557a5

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. but we don't want to extract the whole lib. Instead, we can create a new class PaytmChecksumNew and copy the whole PaytmChecksum class to our new class and update your above line was enough.